# Saving deque to file minding performance and portability

Tags: python, performance, hdf5

I have a while loop that collects data from a microphone (replaced here for `np.random.random()` to make it more reproducible). I do some operations, let's say I take the `abs().mean()` here because my output will be a one dimensional array.

This loop is going to run for a LONG time (e.g., once a second for a week) and I am wondering my options to save this. My main concerns are saving the data with acceptable performance and having the result being portable (e.g, .csv beats .npy).

1. The simple way: just append things into a `.txt` file. Could be replaced by `csv.gz` maybe? Maybe using `np.savetxt()`? Would it be worth it?
2. The hdf5 way: this should be a nicer way, but reading the whole dataset to append to it doesn't seem like good practice or better performing than dumping into a text file. Is there another way to append to hdf5 files?
3. The npy way (code not shown): I could save this into a `.npy` file but I would rather make it portable using a format that could be read from any program.

```
from collections import deque
import numpy as np
import h5py
amplitudes = deque(maxlen=save_interval_sec)
# Read from the microphone in a continuous stream
while True:
    data = np.random.random(100)
    amplitude = np.abs(data).mean()
    print(amplitude, end="\r")
    amplitudes.append(amplitude)

    # Save the amplitudes to a file every n iterations
    if len(amplitudes) == save_interval:
        with open("amplitudes.txt", "a") as f:
            for amp in amplitudes:
                f.write(str(amp) + "\n")
        amplitudes.clear()

    # Save the amplitudes to an HDF5 file every n iterations
    if len(amplitudes) == save_interval:
        # Convert the deque to a Numpy array
        amplitudes_array = np.array(amplitudes)

        # Open an HDF5 file
        with h5py.File("amplitudes.h5", "a") as f:
            # Get the existing dataset or create a new one if it doesn't exist
            dset = f.get("amplitudes")
            if dset is None:
                dset = f.create_dataset("amplitudes", data=amplitudes_array, dtype=np.float32,
                                        maxshape=(None,), chunks=True, compression="gzip")
            else:
                # Get the current size of the dataset
                current_size = dset.shape[0]

                # Resize the dataset to make room for the new data
                dset.resize((current_size + save_interval,))

                # Write the new data to the dataset
                dset[current_size:] = amplitudes_array
        # Clear the deque
        amplitudes.clear()
    # For debug only
    if len(amplitudes)>3:
        break
```

### Update

I get that the answer might depend a bit on the sampling frequency (once a second might be too slow) and the data dimensions (single column might be too little). I guess I asked because *anything* can work, but I always just dump to text. I am not sure where the breaking points are that tip the decision into one or the other method.

Comment: Saving it to a .txt file seems simple and like it would work. Some back of the envelope math shows that it would be 600,000 samples over the course of a week. That's roughly 10MB of data, which is perfectly reasonable.

Comment: Storage devices are slow, but storing data in text is even slower. Writing binary data is faster. However, compression like gzip is slow. IDK if there are faster algorithm provided by the library. Algorithms like LZ4 are much faster (though the compression ratio is less good but there is no free lunch). Note that resizing Numpy array is done in `O(n)` time.

Comment: If the memory size is acceptable, I agree that csv is not a bad choice simply because for long-running processes, it is less likely that you lose all your data due to an application crash at the wrong moment, or running out of disk space in the middle of updating HDF5 metadata. If you want to use a more complex format, consider using new files at least once a day and also activate checksumming, e.g. the [fletcher32 filter in HDF5](https://docs.h5py.org/en/stable/high/dataset.html#fletcher32-filter)

Comment: why deque and why deque is important aspect in this question (so is in the title)?

Comment: @dankal444 Every time I grow data one iteration at a time, I default to using a deque with a buffer length and saving every n iterations. I normally have several strings of data in this way and dump them all to file. The question is about the best way of doing so for processes that are long/memory intensive, balancing the length of the data and the frequency of saving with the space and portability. If you have a better way to do this I would gladly switch to it :)

Comment: @MatiasAndina I think if you are using deque instead of a list you should have a reason to do so. If not, it is confusing for some readers of your code (who, as me, will search for such a reason).